How to avoid getting a 404 Error on Google Maps Routes API
I am trying to use Google Routes API, however it is returning a 404 error. No information on the network tab or anywhere else gives any indication of why this is happening so it is almost impossible to troubleshoot.
Can anyone explain why a 404 error is occuring?
The same API Key worked perfectly fine with Directions Matrix API.
Here is the request below, if you see something wrong, please let us know:
   // Set up the Routes API endpoint and the API key
    const apiKey = 'xxx';  // Replace with your actual API key
    const routesApiUrl = `https://routes.googleapis.com/v2:computeRoutes?key=${apiKey}`;
  
    const directionsTo = $mapElement.data('map-directions-destination');

    $('.directions__form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const directionsFrom = jQuery.trim(jQuery('.directions__postcode').val());
      const requestBody = {
        origins: [`${directionsFrom}`],  // Origin
        destinations: [`${directionsTo}`],  // Destination
        travelMode: 'DRIVE',  // Can be 'DRIVE', 'WALK', 'BICYCLE', etc.
        routingPreference: 'TRAFFIC_AWARE',  // Optional, use 'TRAFFIC_AWARE' to consider traffic
        unitSystem: 'IMPERIAL',  // Optional, specify unit system (e.g., 'IMPERIAL' or 'METRIC')
      };

  // Send the request to the Routes API using fetch
  fetch(routesApiUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With"

    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.routes && data.routes.length > 0) {
      const route = data.routes[0];  // Assuming the first route

      // Prepare data for rendering the directions
      const duration = route.legs[0].duration;
      const distance = route.legs[0].distance;

      // Optionally, you can create a new marker on the map or process the route data
      marker.setMap(null);  // Remove the existing marker (if any)
      
      // Render the directions panel or display turn-by-turn directions
      const directionsPanel = $('.directions__turn-by-turn').get(0);
      directionsPanel.innerHTML = `
        <div>
          <h3>Duration: ${duration.text}</h3>
          <p>Distance: ${distance.text}</p>
          <h4>Directions:</h4>
          <ul>
            ${route.legs[0].steps.map(step => `<li>${step.html_instructions}</li>`).join('')}
          </ul>
        </div>
      `;
      
      // Optional: Render the route on the map (if desired)
      // Example: You could use a polyline or map markers to show the route visually
      const routePath = route.legs[0].steps.map(step => step.polyline);
      const polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: routePath,  // A simplified example; you can refine this based on your actual data
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });
      polyline.setMap(map);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching Routes API:', error);
  });
    });

Here is a screenshot of the response:

I have made a reproducible example here - the API keys have been taken out.
https://codepen.io/JuliusGoddard/pen/emOGzpZ
Before downvoting or closing the thread, please consider that there are very few questions related to Routes API and documentation is scarce.
Furthermore, support for Directions Matrix API runs out on 1 March 2025, therefore many projects are going to lose their map functionality, resulting in many developers facing [problems within the next few months when they inevitably have to migrate from Directions Matrix API to Routes API.
N.B. To get the points from the bounty - you have to be 100% specific in why a 404 is occuring and write exactly how to solve it - no vague answers please.
Thanks in Advance
